# Protractor dragAndDrop not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, protractor, mouseevent

I have tried all possible ways for drag and dropping the  elements available in the below link,

https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop

But i am unable to achieve drag and drop the elements between two boxes.

**Methods i tried so for**

```
1.browser.actions().mouseMove(a).mouseDown().mouseMove(b).mouseUp().perform()
2.browser.actions().dragAndDrop(a,b).perform()
3.browser.driver.actions().dragAndDrop(a,{x:1000,y:0}).perform();
```

All the above methods are not working. Can some one figure out the possible work around for achieve dragAndDrop function on the elements.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The HTML5 drag and drop is not supported by the current drivers. You'll have to trigger the `dragenter`, `dragover` and `drop` events with some JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the information!! @Florent B

Comment: Solved the issue. I have used native Javascript to drag the elements from the link. Found the solution from below link [http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop]

Comment: If you still have it, can you share what the solution ended up being?